# Regex for a string between : and ,

Tags: regex

I have been trying to get values between `:` and `,` for this below string

- String: `key1:value1,key2:value2`
- regex: `(?<=\:)[^:]*(?=\:)`
- result: `value1,key2`
- Expected: `value1,value2`

Any help?

Comment: Is there supposed to be another `,` after `value2`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the part `[^:]*(?=\:)` you will match not a `:` which will match `value1,key2` and will over match it. Then the positive lookahead assertion succeeds because there is a `:` after it.

To get the values between : and , instead of matching not a `:`, you could match not a `,` In the positive lookahead you could assert the end of the string or a comma.

```
(?<=:)[^,]+(?=$|,)
```

**Explanation**

- `(?<=:)` Assert what is directly on the left is `:`
- `[^,]+` Match 1+ times any char other than `,`
- `(?=$|,)` Assert what is directly on the right is the end of string or a `,`

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/izAEjR/1)

Comment: Does this work for Java Regex . am trying use the regex in java code and its giving syntax errors at $ symbol

Comment: Yes that should work. `String regex = "(?<=:)[^,]*(?=$|,)";`

Answer (score 0):

No need for lookaheads or lookbehinds:

```
/:([^,]+),/g
```

1. Match a `:`
2. Capture one or more characters that are *not* a `,`
3. Match a `,`
4. g indicates to match all occurrences in the string

the result of this regular expression will generate two capture groups with `value1` and `value2`